# How to get Boolean value of PWA support Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How to use **SQLite** or other local **DB** when I install the **PWA**.

And

How to get a **boolean value** that, if my app is installed locally or not installed.

**For Example:**

```
    if(PWA installed){
 print('Use local database'); 
}
else{
print('Use server storage');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use install event

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnCEXQo_TiI

```
// install event
self.addEventListener('install', evt => {
  //console.log('service worker installed');
  //DO your db switch
});
```

Same for uninstall, to switch to online or ...

As for check if installed use `appinstalled` event

```
window.addEventListener('appinstalled', (evt) => {
  console.log('app installed');
});
```